# Exception handling the right way for WebClient.DownloadString

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I was wondering what exceptions I should protect myself against when using `WebClient.DownloadString`.

Here's how I'm currently using it, but I'm sure you guys can suggest better more robust exception handling.

For example, off the top of my head:

- No internet connection.
- Server returned a 404.
- Server timed out.

What is the preferred way to handle these cases and throw the exception to the UI?

```
public IEnumerable<Game> FindUpcomingGamesByPlatform(string platform)
{
    string html;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            html = client.DownloadString(GetPlatformUrl(platform));
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            //How do I capture this from the UI to show the error in a message box?
            throw e;
        }
    }

    string relevantHtml = "<tr>" + GetHtmlFromThisYear(html);
    string[] separator = new string[] { "<tr>" };
    string[] individualGamesHtml = relevantHtml.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);

    return ParseGames(individualGamesHtml);           
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you catch `WebException`, it should handle most cases. `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest` throw a `WebException` for all HTTP protocol errors (4xx and 5xx), and also for network level errors (disconnection, host not reachable, etc)

---

> How do I capture this from the UI to show the error in a message box?

I'm not sure I understand your question... Can't you just show the exception message?

```
MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
```

Don't catch the exception in `FindUpcomingGamesByPlatform`, let it bubble up to the calling method, catch it there and show the message...

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I guess I was asking how to bubble the exception error. :)

Answer (score 9):

I usually handle it like this to print any exception message the remote server is returning. Given that the users are allowed to see that value.

```
try
{
    getResult = client.DownloadString(address);
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    String responseFromServer = ex.Message.ToString() + " ";
    if (ex.Response != null)
    {
        using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
        {
            Stream dataRs = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataRs))
            {
                responseFromServer += reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    _log.Error("Server Response: " + responseFromServer);
    MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this code:

1. Here I `init` the webclient whithin the loaded event

   ```
   private void LayoutRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     // download from web async
     var client = new WebClient();
     client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
     client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://whateveraurisingis.com"));
   }
   ```
2. The callback

   ```
   void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
     #region handle download error
     string download = null;
     try
     {
       download = e.Result;
     }
   catch (Exception ex)
     {
       MessageBox.Show(AppMessages.CONNECTION_ERROR_TEXT, AppMessages.CONNECTION_ERROR, MessageBoxButton.OK);
     }

     // check if download was successful
     if (download == null)
     {
       return;
     }
     #endregion

     // in my example I parse a xml-documend downloaded above      
     // parse downloaded xml-document
     var dataDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(download));

     //... your code
   }
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx), the only non-programmer exception is `WebException`, which can be raised if:

> The URI formed by combining BaseAddress and address is invalid.
>
> -or-
>
> An error occurred while downloading the resource.